# 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method' error android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Below I've written the function where I'm getting the error, which is -

> "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setWebViewClient(WebViewClient) from the type WebView".

The line I'm getting it has `****` at its beginning. How to correct this error?

```
public class Webview extends Activity {

WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    //webviewclient
    WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
       {
           // Override page so it's load on my view only
           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
           {
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return true;
           }
       };

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
****    WebView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: You are using  WebView class, not the webview object you've created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
```

to:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
```

By capitalizing the "W" in `webView`, you're referring to the to the class `android.webkit.WebView`. This makes Java look for a static method called `setWebViewClient()` in that class, which it doesn't find, and hence throws an error.

Comment: Oh yeah got it, this bugged me for an hour haha.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are referring to the class WebView. Not your object webView. Notice the lowercase 'w'